# What would you understand if someone told you "you don't pay your tailor enough"?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

It seems that it can be interpreted in a positive or negative way. Positive in the sense that your dress looks great and you should pay the tailor even more. Negative in the sense that the dress looks terrible because you are cheap with your tailor. Therefore, is it correct to think that the real meaning depends on how that sentence is said?

Comment: As with many English expressions, the context matters. Without some context it's impossible to know for sure, can you provide the context in which this is used?

Comment: I've looked on Google Books and Google for examples but, although it sounds natural enough, I cannot find this set of words.  *is it correct to think that the real meaning depends on how that sentence is said?* Yes - it is impossible to overstate the importance of context and tone in English.

Comment: It's a riff on "you get what you pay for". As far as I'm concerned, the positive sense is impossible. The statement is inherently vitriolic and sarcastic. It's what you say to your arch rival as they are walking in to a meeting with the bigwigs. The implication is that it is in the tailor's best interest to sabotage the looks of their cheaper clients. The positive version would be something like "you can't pay your tailor too much", but that isn't how you compliment someone else on their looks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, considered apart from the context and from the manner in which it is uttered, the sentence is ambiguous: the intended meaning could be 'The outfit looks so good that the tailor deserves to be paid more than he was actually paid' or 'The outfit looks bad, probably because you did not pay the tailor enough to motivate him of produce something better'. Whether it is more frequently used in the first or the second sense is debatable; a reasonable guess is that the former use is somewhat more frequent, simply because people are more likely to compliment others on their looks than criticise them. In any event, in almost any real-life situation, the context and the tone of voice are likely to disambiguate the sentence.

Comment: The answer is posted as a wiki, because it would not be proper for anybody to claim credit for merely confirming what was in the question, but it is still important, for the benefit of both the OP and the future visitors to this page, that such a confirmation be posted among the answers. The OP should, however, note that this site is not well geared to the questions that call for answers that merely say 'Yes, you are right'.

Answer (score 0):

Since the person talking to you doesn’t know how much you paid your tailor, it’s negative and equivalent to saying that your clothes look cheap or fit badly.

But note that tailors do men’s clothes, usually, not dresses. So it’s nonidiomatic to start with.

Comment: It's not necessarily nonidiomatic. 'Dress' can mean clothing of any type. Consider 'dress codes' for work, they apply to both men and women and to women wearing skirts and blouses and trouser suits as well as 'dresses'.

Comment: The OP believes that the sentence is ambiguous, i.e. that, considered apart from the context and from the manner in which it is uttered, it has two possible meanings. You seem confident that only one of these meanings is possible. What exactly is the argument for ruling out the other?

Comment: @jsw29 It seems to me that the effort to construct a scenario in which the sentence could be taken literally is futile and unhelpful. It’s leading the op to believe that it is in fact extremely difficult to figure out meaning  and that expressions conventionally used to mean one thing can be used to mean another without doing harm to the use of language.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like idiom
It might be meaning as "not giving enough consideration for any thing have gotten."